# Angular JS from validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

Iam new to Angular JS. I am writing a login form. the requirement is show a custom message when the user clicks the submit button and the username field is blank.

```
      <md-input-container>
            <label>{{::vm.labels.username}}</label>
            <input ng-model="vm.oLoginData.sUsername" **required**>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
```

Everything is fine on click of the submit button i get the pop up on the filed " please fill out this field". My question is is there a way to customize the message? If so How. Any help will be much appriciated

Comment: The new mesage they what is "Username Field cannot be blank"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code at the plnkr link
http://plnkr.co/edit/ngSZN9wjOzVItbf3QU4D?p=preview

I am highlighting the main sections of the code
load the module after Angular and then inject it into our application.

```
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>

HTML
 <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" 
                ng-model="main.name"
                ng-minlength="5"
                ng-maxlength="10"
                required>

            <!-- ngMessages goes here -->
        </div>
<!-- Include the help block for messages over here-->
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.email.$error" ng-if="userForm.email.$touched">
        <div ng-messages-include="messages.html"></div>
   </div>

In the message.html
Add the code

    <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
    <p ng-message="minlength">This field is too short</p>
    <p ng-message="maxlength">This field is too long</p>
    <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
    <p ng-message="email">This needs to be a valid email</p>

In the app.js

    angular
      .module('app', ['ngMessages'])
      .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

    function MainCtrl() {

    }
```

Comment: I have one more question ... can u please tell me how are you hiding the validation text once all the validation criteria is satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

Check demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b91767c/2/).

Use something like:

```
<div ng-show="vm.oLoginData.sUsername.$dirty && vm.oLoginData.sUsername.$invalid">
     The user name is required. Please fill in.
</div>
```

Comment: i tried the div but now the whole issue is that the user like the pop up bubble but they want custom message

Comment: What kind of popup you are using? Bootstrap ui?

Comment: The popup is actually just DOM element, you may try to modify the CSS to make as popup.

Comment: iam not sure ... we do have bootstrap... As i said iam new to Angular

Comment: Thanks for that Joy ... I better do something like that

Answer (score 0):

See if this works,

```
<span ng-show="name.$error.nameblank">Username Field cannot be blank</span>
```

And in the directive you use,

```
ngModel.$setValidity("nameblank",false);
```

Give it a try.

Comment: tried this aslo but now the whole issue is that the user like the pop up bubble but they want custom message in that bubble

Comment: You would use the `setValidity` when you want to display the message. You will need to write codes to check whether the name is blank. Are you sure you're doing this right?   
I need to go right now, I'll get back to this in the afternoon if you need help.